# Batch: Don't parse comment of key-value

Tags: parsing, batch-file, ini

I am using the following code to parse an config.ini-file:

```
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off
set file=%~1
set area=[%~2]
set key=%~3
set currarea=
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("!file!") do (
    set ln=%%a
    if "x!ln:~0,1!"=="x[" (
        set currarea=!ln!
    ) else (
        for /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%b in ("!ln!") do (
            set currkey=%%b
            set currval=%%c
            if "x!area!"=="x!currarea!" if "x!key!"=="x!currkey!" (
                echo !currval!
            )
        )
    )
)
endlocal
```

It works fine as long as there are no comments in the same line as they keys and values.

For example:

```
 [BACKUP]
 HOST=128.110.111.11   ;Comment is included in !currval!
 PORT=5901
 USER=user1
```

Unfortunately I can't find a way to exclude everything after the last character of the string "128.110.111.11"..

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: read the set commands help file regarding substring modification - `Set /?`. It's a two step process as you first need to use an intermediary variable remove the leading component of the string (Eg: `Set "tmpstr=!OrigVar:*;=!"`) and then perform another substring modification to subtract that remaining value from the original string (Eg: `For %%R in ("!tmpstr!")Do Set "OrigVar=!OrigVar:%%~R=!"`). Further steps may be required to remove trailing spaces

Comment: Trailing comments are not properly supported and should not therefore be used. Have you seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19550081)? Regardless, you could still probably use the semicolon as a delimiter, _(instead of just the `=` character)_, then remove any trailing whitespace characters from the resultant string. Or in the limited case example you've provided, use the space character as a delimiter too, and change the tokens accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your answers.

I didn't know that trailing comments are not supported. So it might be the best way to just avoid doing this and leaving my .bat script as it is.

Comment: What's the purpose of the preceding `x`s in your `if` comparisons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best batch has to offer towards achieving the goal is a combination of for loops to process the string. There is no innate command that can achieve this in a single step.

In a way though, you can make a command to complete the necessary set of commands by a assigning them to a variable as a macro

For example, in the below script the macro completes the necessary steps for this goal by:

- Delimitng the Variables content using `;`
- Iterating over the length of the string from end to start - The example assumes a maximum string length of 250 characters; an arbitrary number for the point of the example.
- Remove only trailing spaces using If condition logic and substring modification
- Stop further modification of the variables content by using a true/false switch to flag that the last digit of the string contains a non-space character

Note : Substring modification is used at the point of the the macros expansion to supply the name of the variable to be processed.

```bat
@Echo off & Setlocal enableDelayedexpansion
 Set "RemTrail=Set "end=0"&(For /F "Tokens=1 Delims=;" %%G in ("^^!$v^^!")Do Set "$V=%%G")&For /L %%i in (250,-1,0)Do (if "^^!$V:~%%i,1^^!"==" " (If not "^^!End^^!"=="1" Set "$V=^^!$V:~0,%%i^^!")Else (If not "^^!$V:~%%i,1^^!"=="" Set "End=1"))"
rem // usage  example
 Set "string=trail of spaces    ; comment string  "
 Set "string2=uncommented string with trailing spaces and poison chars < &  " " | * >  "
Echo/[!string!]
Echo/[!string2!]
 %RemTrail:$V=String%
 %RemTrail:$V=String2%
Echo/[!string!]
Echo/[!string2!]
```

A slighty modified version that Allows the Delimiter to be modified at expansion, at the expense of returning the modified result in a fixed return variable (`$V`) instead of the original variable name:

```bat
@Echo off & Setlocal enableDelayedexpansion
 Set "RemTrail=For %%n in (1 2)Do if %%n==2 (Set "end=0"&(For /F "Tokens=1 Delims=DLM" %%G in ("^^!$V^^!")Do Set "$V=%%~G")&For /L %%i in (250,-1,0)Do (if "^^!$V:~%%i,1^^!"==" " (If not "^^!End^^!"=="1" Set "$V=^^!$V:~0,%%i^^!")Else (If not "^^!$V:~%%i,1^^!"=="" Set "End=1")))Else Set $V="
rem // usage  example
 Set "string=trail of spaces    ; comment string  "
 Set "string2=uncommented string with trailing spaces + poison chars < & | * " " >  "
Echo/[!string!]
Echo/[!string2!]
 %RemTrail:DLM=;%"!string!"
Echo/[!$V!]
 %RemTrail:DLM=;%"!string2!"
Echo/[!$V!]
 %RemTrail:DLM=+%"!string2!"
Echo/+ Delim example&Echo/[!$V!]
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1:

```
for /f "usebackq delims=;" %%a in ("!file!") do (
```

Including the semicolon as a delimiter ensures only that part of the line up to, but not including the semicolon is assigned to `token 1` which is assigned by default to the metavariable `%%a`

Disadvantage : the spaces between the end of the string and the semicolon are retained in `%%a` and hence `currval` and will be `echo`ed.

Solution 2 :

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims== " %%b in ("!ln!") do (
```

Inclusion of the space as an extra delimiter will assign the value between the first delimiter found (`=`) and the second ([space]) to `%%c`.

Disadvantage : The value displayed as `%%c` will be truncated at the space

Solution 3:

Use solution 1 and then change

```
    set currval=%%c
```

to

```
    CALL :setcurrval %%c
```

AND then `endlocal` becomes

```
endlocal
goto :eof

:setcurrval
SET "currval=%*"
goto :eof
```

which terminates the local environment and exits the batch.
`CALL`ing the internal subroutine `:setcurrval` assigns the value of the remainder of the line to `currval`, except for the terminal spaces, hence producing `%%c` minus any terminal spaces.

Note that the colons are significant.