# Double slash to disable line in .ini file?

Tags: ini

Is it a double slash (//) that disables a line in an `ini` file?

For example:

```
[SystemSettings]
r.SceneColorFringeQuality=0 
// r.MotionBlur.Max=0  //
```

Or would this be correct?

```
[SystemSettings]
r.SceneColorFringeQuality=0 
; r.MotionBlur.Max=0
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do standard windows .ini files allow comments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378219/do-standard-windows-ini-files-allow-comments)

Comment: Depends on what you're using to parse that file. Usually, the second one will work.

Answer (score 0):

Backslash is: `\`

Forward slash is: `/`

Comments in `.ini` file start with `#` or `;`

Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file

Comment: thank you. i did see that other post as it was suggested when i posted. i didn't think to call it a comment at first.

the post says to use semicolon so do both semicolon and hash work?

Comment: yes, both work.

Comment: awesome, thanks for the help. i will make this the answer in 5 minutes

Comment: @DougieFuoco did you forget to mark the answer?