# Does anyone have a Dependency graph and topological sorting code snippet for PowerShell?

Tags: algorithm, powershell, msbuild, dependencies, powershell-2.0

We were trying to parallelize our build with dependency graph and topological sorting.

All our build logic is written in Msbuild and we are using powershell to call it.

Has any one implemented dependency graph and topological sorting using powershell?

I know that in unix there is a utility called tsort available. Is there any thing similar available in powershell?

This article gives good idea but it is done in C# "[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd569760.aspx"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd569760.aspx)

Comment: You can simply implement it in C#, load a DLL and use it from PowerShell. You can even do that inline with `Add-Type`.

Comment: I did this for Ant with yEd for the visualization and GraphML for the format... I should blog about it and post back here.  :)

Comment: @JasonMArcher: buddy did you write a post?

Comment: Have you looked at [psake](https://github.com/psake/psake/blob/master/psake.psm1)?

Comment: MSBuild also supports multi-core builds starting with vs2008, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx) look for  `/maxcpucount:number`.

Answer (score 8):

I did a quick translation of [Wikipedia's Topological Sort Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting#Algorithms):

```
function Get-TopologicalSort {
  param(
      [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
      [hashtable] $edgeList
  )

  # Make sure we can use HashSet
  Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Core

  # Clone it so as to not alter original
  $currentEdgeList = [hashtable] (Get-ClonedObject $edgeList)

  # algorithm from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting#Algorithms
  $topologicallySortedElements = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
  $setOfAllNodesWithNoIncomingEdges = New-Object System.Collections.Queue

  $fasterEdgeList = @{}

  # Keep track of all nodes in case they put it in as an edge destination but not source
  $allNodes = New-Object -TypeName System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[object] -ArgumentList (,[object[]] $currentEdgeList.Keys)

  foreach($currentNode in $currentEdgeList.Keys) {
      $currentDestinationNodes = [array] $currentEdgeList[$currentNode]
      if($currentDestinationNodes.Length -eq 0) {
          $setOfAllNodesWithNoIncomingEdges.Enqueue($currentNode)
      }

      foreach($currentDestinationNode in $currentDestinationNodes) {
          if(!$allNodes.Contains($currentDestinationNode)) {
              [void] $allNodes.Add($currentDestinationNode)
          }
      }

      # Take this time to convert them to a HashSet for faster operation
      $currentDestinationNodes = New-Object -TypeName System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[object] -ArgumentList (,[object[]] $currentDestinationNodes )
      [void] $fasterEdgeList.Add($currentNode, $currentDestinationNodes)        
  }

  # Now let's reconcile by adding empty dependencies for source nodes they didn't tell us about
  foreach($currentNode in $allNodes) {
      if(!$currentEdgeList.ContainsKey($currentNode)) {
          [void] $currentEdgeList.Add($currentNode, (New-Object -TypeName System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[object]))
          $setOfAllNodesWithNoIncomingEdges.Enqueue($currentNode)
      }
  }

  $currentEdgeList = $fasterEdgeList

  while($setOfAllNodesWithNoIncomingEdges.Count -gt 0) {        
      $currentNode = $setOfAllNodesWithNoIncomingEdges.Dequeue()
      [void] $currentEdgeList.Remove($currentNode)
      [void] $topologicallySortedElements.Add($currentNode)

      foreach($currentEdgeSourceNode in $currentEdgeList.Keys) {
          $currentNodeDestinations = $currentEdgeList[$currentEdgeSourceNode]
          if($currentNodeDestinations.Contains($currentNode)) {
              [void] $currentNodeDestinations.Remove($currentNode)

              if($currentNodeDestinations.Count -eq 0) {
                  [void] $setOfAllNodesWithNoIncomingEdges.Enqueue($currentEdgeSourceNode)
              }                
          }
      }
  }

  if($currentEdgeList.Count -gt 0) {
      throw "Graph has at least one cycle!"
  }

  return $topologicallySortedElements
}
```

This depends on

```
# Idea from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7468707/deep-copy-a-dictionary-hashtable-in-powershell 
function Get-ClonedObject {
    param($DeepCopyObject)
    $memStream = new-object IO.MemoryStream
    $formatter = new-object Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter
    $formatter.Serialize($memStream,$DeepCopyObject)
    $memStream.Position=0
    $formatter.Deserialize($memStream)
}
```

And you use it like this

```
# Sort the Wikipedia example:
Get-TopologicalSort @{11=@(7,5);8=@(7,3);2=@(11);9=@(11,8);10=@(11,3)}
```

Which yields:

```
7
5
3
11
8
10
2
9
```