# Powershell 3 clone an object has unexpected results - affects other object

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, import-csv

I have a problem with a sample of code I am writing. It is a bit of a simple question but it is an issue that has taken some time, which I do not have. I already tried the stackoverflow relevant questions and search but did not find anything that helps a lot.

I have the following code:

```
#Importing some file from a csv to a variable
$output = import-csv -LiteralPath ...some file imports OK

##
#Copy the layout of the csv imported for further processing..
##
$extraOut = $output.clone() 
$extraOut | ForEach-Object {
$_.innerlinks1 = ""
$_.innerlinksurl1 = ""
}
```

When I try to print out the value of $output, by using $_ I get the empty strings that I previously assigned (which I do not want). Why does this happen?

```
#Trying to print out $output should have data and not empty strings.
$output | ForEach-Object { Write-Host $_ }
```

Any help, or code that allows to copy the structure of an Import-csv result (with or without PSObject cloning) would also be great.

NOTE: After finding a helpful answer, I also think that the problem needs more detailed scripting since there is a lot of empty strings in my file that might cause additional issues in the future.

Comment: Array's clone method performs a *shallow* copy, it doesn't clone elements. Look for examples of proper (deep) cloning, there are lots.

Comment: I did try using `.PSObject.copy()` but got the same results. I am already on to it.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I did try that in a  ForEach-Object but did not work as expected. Yes it is an array of one level of objects like so:
`@{name=;name2=} @{name=;name2=} etc..`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the answer in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9204829/deep-copying-a-psobject) whenever I need to deep copy an array. To quote the original answer:

```
# Get original data
$data = Import-Csv ...

# Serialize and Deserialize data using BinaryFormatter
$ms = New-Object System.IO.MemoryStream
$bf = New-Object System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter
$bf.Serialize($ms, $data)
$ms.Position = 0
$data2 = $bf.Deserialize($ms)
$ms.Close()

# Use deep copied data
$data2
```

Comment: I believe that this is the closest answer to the temporary one that I have already found.

Comment: After a bit more searching I did find a couple more related answers to yours, in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7468707/deep-copy-a-dictionary-hashtable-in-powershell) and in [GitHub as a gist](https://gist.github.com/zippy1981/2006846)