# Best way for multiple Variable Declaration in PowerShell

Tags: powershell-3.0

What is the best way to declare input variables that we want to use in a script?

As of now I either declare all the needed variables above the script or create a separate `VariableDeclaration.ps1` and dot-source it in the main script.

Is there a better way to get this done?

Reason I want to do this is because I want to make it easy for my peers to use the script without having much knowledge of scripting. They can easily edit the variables defined in a separate file (maybe INI or XML) without touching the main script.

Any suggestions?

Variables declaration sample:

```bsh
#Customer_details
$CustomerID = '100'
$CustomerName = "ABCorp"
$vCenterName = "vCenter.ABCorp.com"
$vCenterUserName = "administrator@vsphere.local"
$vCenterPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "ABCorp123" -AsPlainText -Force;
$CustomerPODLocation = "VW1"
$DatacenterName = "ABCorpDC"
$ClusterName = "ABCorpcluster"
$InfraResourcePoolName = $CustomerID + "-" + $CustomerName + "-" + "Infrastructure"
$FolderName = $CustomerID + "-" + $CustomerName
$ConnectionType = "S2S"
$VLANID = '237'
$PortGroupName = $ConnectionType  + "-" + $CustomerID + "-" + $CustomerName + "-" + $VLANID
$NumberofPorts = '1024'
```

Comment: `Best` is subjective. For whom? Do they change it often? Are there any problems currently?

Comment: Yes , peers need to change it every time they run 
@wOxxOm : The problem now is that the variable are defined in the main script file so that feels like unsafe for the main coding part . I don't want any unintended person to make any changes there .

An example/sample would be a good help

Comment: Well, for some people an Excel file might be much better. Quite a plausible option I'd say.

Answer (score 0):

The "best way" is quite subjective. It really depends on what you want to achieve and who will be editing the file. Dot-sourcing a .ps1 file basically means that you're executing that script (in the current context instead of a child context like regular execution would). Which is required for your sample file, because it contains not only data, but also code (`ConvertTo-SecureString`, concatenation operations).

Having code in a configuration file may prove problematic, because anyone who is able to edit the file could put arbitrary code in it. Other formats don't have this disadvantage, but might require [additional code for parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/422529/1630171) (INI) or are more difficult to edit for humans (XML).

Perhaps the best compromise is to use a flat file with `key=value` entries and parse it via [`ConvertFrom-StringData`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/3.0/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-stringdata):

```bsh
$config = Get-Content 'C:\path\to\config.txt' -Raw | ConvertFrom-StringData
```

That will create a hashtable from the key/value pairs in the config file. The file format is similar to INI, but not quite the same (no sections allowed, comments start with `#` instead of `;`).

Configurations files aren't the best place for all kind of data, though. Normally you'd put static information in a configuration file, and make information that is bound to change frequently a [parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/3.0/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parameters) to the script.

Example:

`config.ps1`:

```bsh
$foo = 'something'   # static information, unlikely to change between script runs
...
```

`script.ps1`:

```bsh
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
  # required value that is likely to change between script runs
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
  [string]$Bar,

  # default value that works most of the time, but which you want to
  # be able to override on the fly
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
  [int]$Baz = 42,

  ...
)

# read static configuration
. .\config.ps1

...
```

Note that it's usually bad practice to store plaintext credentials in a file. If your scripts are intended for interactive use you may want to consider prompting for credentials instead of putting them in a file.