# Update text file using between two section using powershell

Tags: string, powershell

I want to check the text between [section3] and [section4] and insert a new line after line 4.
How i can do it using powershell, any pointers to do that ?

**Sample.txt**

```
 [Section1]
 around 100Lines of text
[Section2]
 around 100Lines of text
[Section3]
Line1
Line2
Line3
Line4
Line5
Line6
[Section4]
100Lines of test
[Section5]
```

Comment: Are you parsing an INI file?

Comment: @vonPryz: Yes, correct

Comment: Does this answer your question? [INI file parsing in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417798/ini-file-parsing-in-powershell)

Comment: Try a dedicated [INI parser](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PsIni) instead of rolling your own solution.