# Generalised configuration file parser in powershell

Tags: powershell, parsing, configuration-files

I'm looking for a generalised solution for parsing configuration files to and from powershell objects.

In this specific instance I have an Oracle TNSNames file, however I have other configuration files which are not as well recognised and don't have parser modules already available.

```
VIZRTDB =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (FAILOVER=TRUE)
    (LOAD_BALANCE=FALSE)
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS_LIST =
        (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 10.35.36.111)(PORT = 1521))
      )
      (CONNECT_DATA =
        (SERVER = DEDICATED)
        (SERVICE_NAME = VCPGTV)
      )
    )

    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS_LIST =
        (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 10.109.36.112)(PORT = 1521))
      )
      (CONNECT_DATA =
        (SERVER = DEDICATED)
        (SERVICE_NAME = VCPHUB)
      )
    )
  )


VCPGTV =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 10.35.36.111)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = VCPGTV)
    )
  )
```

Which I'd like to convert into an object represented by the following PSON;

```
@{ "VIZRTDB"= @(
        @{"DESCRIPTION_LIST"= @(
                @{"FAILOVER"= @("TRUE")},
                @{"LOAD_BALANCE"= @("FALSE")},
                @{"DESCRIPTION"= @(
                        @{"ADDRESS_LIST"= @(
                                @{"ADDRESS"= @(
                                        @{"PROTOCOL"= @("TCP")},
                                        @{"HOST"= @("10.35.36.111")},
                                        @{"PORT"= @("1521")}
                                )}
                        )},
                        @{"CONNECT_DATA"= @(
                                @{"SERVER"= @("DEDICATED")},
                                @{"SERVICE_NAME"= @("VCPGTV")}
                        )}
                )},
                @{"DESCRIPTION"= @(
                        @{"ADDRESS_LIST"= @(
                                @{"ADDRESS"= @(
                                        @{"PROTOCOL"= @("TCP")},
                                        @{"HOST"= @("10.109.36.112")},
                                        @{"PORT"= @("1521")}
                                )}
                        )},
                        @{"CONNECT_DATA"= @(
                                @{"SERVER"= @("DEDICATED")},
                                @{"SERVICE_NAME"= @("VCPHUB")}
                        )}
                )}
        )}
);
"VCPGTV"= @(
        @{"DESCRIPTION"= @(
                @{"ADDRESS"= @(
                        @{"PROTOCOL"= @("TCP")},
                        @{"HOST"= @("10.35.36.111")},
                        @{"PORT"= @("1521")}
                )},
                @{"CONNECT_DATA"= @(
                        @{"SERVER"= @("DEDICATED")},
                        @{"SERVICE_NAME"= @("VCPGTV")}
                )}
        )}
)}
```

Then specific values of the configuration can now be changed and written back.

I've managed to perform 95% of the conversion using `[Management.Automation.psParser]::tokenize` with a heap of `if` statements to create the PSON. It then requires minor tweaks in a text editor to get it all the way.  It's then fairly easy to modify the code to produce other notations like `JSON` or `XML`.

Now that I have the configuration file tokenized, I'm looking to parse it, maybe using `BNF` to describe how it's built and create a representation in a `PSObject`.

Of course I haven't begun to investigate how to convert a `PSObject` back into a serialized configuration file.

These are my possible ideas;

1. find and use equivalents of `flex` and `bison` and `BNF`.
2. Find appropriate classes and methods in `.net` or `system.management.automation.*`
3. Look at the source for cmdlets like `convertfrom-json` and create a custom cmdlet by modifying the parser code.
4. convert to `XML` and use xml libraries for modification and `XSLT` to convert back into tnsnames format.

Other ideas, suggestions, libraries, methods and commands appreciated.

Comment: I think option 3 may be your best bet here. Modifying an existing module to suit your needs should result in the lowest-effort, highest-success solution. Alternatively, converting to XML will open up a lot of possibilities to use existing modules, but won't converting also require some form of parser, thus invalidating the whole point? I say go for option 3.

Comment: Also take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417798/ini-file-parsing-in-powershell). It covers a very similar topic and the top answer suggests much the same - making a compact parser with regular expressions.